# Mercurial trust issues

Tags: mercurial, trust

I am trying to set up a hook to notify me about new commits via mail.

Because of the issue described in [Mercurial hook not executing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848627/mercurial-hook-not-executing-properly), I can't seem to get it running by simply adding the following to my `.hg/hgrc`, since the script wouldn't run:

```
[hooks]  
changegroup = /path/to/script
```

As a workaround, I added the hook in the `hgweb.config` where it runs as expected. Now since I'm pushing through HTTP, the actual user running the script is `apache` (as determined by running `id` from within the hook), which means that I get errors like

> Not trusting file .hg/hgrc from untrusted user u, group g

I added

```
[trusted]  
users = u
```

but the same errors remain. What am I doing wrong? Am I understanding this completly wrong? Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add both the hook and the trust blocks not in the `hgweb.config` but in a `.hgrc` file in the apache user's home directory.  One doesn't usually think of system users having home directories, but they all do, and you can find in in `/etc/password`.  It's often something like `/var/www`, so if you create a `/var/www/.hgrc` file, make sure it's owned by the Apache user, and add the hook and the trust you'll be good to go.

Comment: You're totally right, putting it in the `hgweb.config` is as ugly as it can be, but it's still more local than it would be in `/var/www/.hgrc` which is why I'm preferring it. We now found the error to result from what appears to be a misconfiguration of the server, erroneously declaring /root to be the webserver's homedir which resulted in it failing to read the correct configuration file. The `trusted` configuration was therefore completely ignored.

Comment: Jonny, I see that a lot.  I always put the absolute path to the hgweb.config file in the hgweb.cgi script -- counting on the webserver's current working dir breaks across CGI, FCGI, and WSGI and different servers.