# hg changegroup hook - suppress specific output from hg?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

I have written a changegroup hook that is invoked in my local repository when I pull changes from the remote server copy. In the hook implementation, I invoke hg update to pull in the changes. On running `hg pull`command, the output shows as follows:

```
pulling from ssh://lava@lava.in/hgrepo
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files  
Verified file test1.cpp
(run 'hg update' to get a working copy)
```

Since I am already invoking `hg update` in the hook, I want to suppress the last line that suggests user to run `hg update`.

Answer (score 1):

There's [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848627/mercurial-hook-not-executing-properly) that might be useful.

Also, if you are doing this just for yourself, you could achieve the same result with an alias for `pull -u`; I use an alias called `get` and I tend to just run `hg get` to effect a pull and update.

If you are using TortoiseHg, you can add `postpull = update` under the `[tortoisehg]` section in the appropriate file (`.hgrc/hgrc/mercurial.ini`) and that will take care of updating your working directory after you fetch remote changes using the Workbench.